# Can't make requirements in composer

Tags: apt, package-management, composer

I'm trying to use GuzzleHttp, but I have `'Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found'` all the time. I googled, and everyone says to make `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle` in the project folder. But when i type it in console I have

```
Using version ^6.3 for guzzlehttp/guzzle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of 
packages.

 Problem 1
- don't install bower-asset/yii2-pjax 2.0.7.1|remove yiisoft/yii2-app-basic No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)
- remove yiisoft/yii2-app-basic No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)|remove bower-asset/yii2-pjax 2.0.7.1
- don't install bower-asset/yii2-pjax 2.0.7.1|remove yiisoft/yii2-app-basic No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)
- Installation request for yiisoft/yii2-app-basic No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-app-basic[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)].
- Installation request for bower-asset/yii2-pjax (locked at 2.0.7.1) -> satisfiable by bower-asset/yii2-pjax[2.0.7.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I tried to remove this `remove yiisoft/yii2-app-basic` but output is
`yiisoft/yii2-app-basic is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed
Package "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files`

composer.json in my project

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.14",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0 || ~2.1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.3"
},
```

If it will help, I have globally installed composer via `sudo apt-get install composer`

Comment: Do you mean [Guzzle related to PHP](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=guzzle&searchon=names) ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I decided to reinstall composer according to the [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-ubuntu-18-04), but I had Installation corrupt instead of verified, so I started to dig in this direction. I had some troubles with snapd, I found solution in stackoverflow, but cant find the link. Then I installed composer but problem didn't gone, I thought that I installed it wrongly again. But before reinstalling I typed `composer update` in my project folder, and it started deleting bower-assets e.t.c. I was so happy, after `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle` worked fine. But the new errors accured `The file or directory to be published does not exist: /home/xxx/yyy/zzz/vendor/bower-asset/jquery/dist`

I tried every suggested [solution](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6402). But nothing helped, so I decided to create new project. Then required guzzle and now everything works fine. I suppose that the initial problem was in composer and snapd. I hope this article will help someone.